# Can't connect my html doc to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML,

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='editor-script.js'></script>
```

I had put the `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` in the same folder as jQuery but whenever I run code in jQuery the HTML acts like the code isn't there.

```
$.ready(function(){
    $("#file-tab").click(function(){
        $("#file-tab").append('<div id="tab-file"></div>');
    });
});
```

What i'm trying to run on jQuery^ (it's file name is `editor-script.js`).
`file-tab` is a `div` id in the HTML file.

Comment: already tried $(document).ready... 
thanks anyways

Comment: Check for any errors in your browser console and add them to your question. Any chance you could provide a JSFiddle example?

Comment: An obvious question but since the paths to the scripts are relative - are they in the same folder (the root) of your HTML index file?

Comment: One more thing to add - even though I see a comment that another piece of code to check for doc ready was tried and despite the fact that there are several variations to approach it, "$.ready(function() {" isn't one that will work (just tried to be sure, you never know).

Answer (score 1):

Your `ready` event is incorrect.
The recommended way is:

```
$(document).ready(...);
```

Or this: (though **not** recommended by jQuery)

```
$().ready(...);
```

Or:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

I just did an alert in the jQuery file and it worked. That means it's properly linked up to the file. I changed the code to `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: This isn't an answer, you should just put this as a comment

Comment: @Coderchu It is an answer. It answers the question. From no corner I see this as NAA.